# What is the state of a TextArea in the Flex when we could not enter the cursor in it and no text is passed into it

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I need to know that what is the state or property of text-area in the flex when we could not enter the text in it, my concern is that whether the text has entered(may after it deleted) or not.
(I think i try my best to explain my problem)
Thanks

Thanks of all of you that you provide the solution/answer

Comment: Were the answers correct? Maybe you'll check the most sutable answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both MX and Spark `TextAreas` supports `editable` and `selectable` properties. The first one prevent user to change text, the second - to select it:

```
<mx:TextArea editable="false" selectable="false"
    text="Sample Text"/>

<s:TextArea editable="false" selectable="false"
    text="Sample Text"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand your problem, but it sounds like it could be the Safari 5.1 / Flash Debug player bug. Try switching to another browser when debugging/testing your project. If you get the same behaviour, forget everything I just said.

Read more here:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/15666579#15666579

"I also don't think this was intentional at all.  I think it was just a bit careless (Apple pushing out Safari 5.1 before it being thoroughly tested - the flash problem is only one of several issues I've noted with the new browser.  Very dissapointing.)."

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about [MX `TextArea`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextArea.html) you can disable component:

```
myTextArea.enabled = false;
```

If you're using [Spark `TextArea`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextArea.html) you can use [`editable` property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#editable).